# Lists are not working in spoiler blocks

Tags: support, bug, spoilers, markdown

Consider this following spoiler block:

> The quick brown fox:
>
>  * Jumped over the lazy dog
>  * And did something else.

It should have one paragraph, then a bulleted list with two items - just as if it were not in a quoted non-spoiler block:

> The quick brown fox:
>
> - Jumped over the lazy dog
> - And did something else.

Or no block at all:

The quick brown fox:

- Jumped over the lazy dog
- And did something else.

... but that's not what happening. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Spoiler markdown doesn't really work well with other markdown. This is pretty much by design as we don't want too much content being hidden.

That said you can insert a list into spoiler markdown by using plain HTML like the below:

```
>! The quick brown fox:
>!
>! <ul>
>!   <li>Jumped over the lazy dog</li>
>!   <li>And did something else.</li>
>! </ul>
```

Which renders as the below:

> The quick brown fox:
>
> - Jumped over the lazy dog
> - And did something else.

Comment: Breaking spoiler markdown doesn't seem like the reasonable way to discourage long spoilers.

Comment: @einpoklum It's not breaking spoiler markdown, it's a lack of features for it... which is a bit different.